# Visual Studio Online creates empty drop

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Project nature: C++ , native, console project) , one dll project, two exe projects , the exe are meant for test case

I am using new script based build(not XAML based,  at least that is my understanding).

Locally I am able to create dll, executable, run test cases and get code coverage.

The patform toolset is set to : "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)"

The "Output Directory" is set to

$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a task called: Publish Build Artifacts to specify the drop location and manage the vNext build artifacts.

More detailed information, you can refer to: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/